# Geth --dev mode; define reward account for mining

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, testnets, genesis

If I set up a development testnet on geth and start mining, what account number gets the rewards?

What command can I use to define the mining account?

**Console1:**

```
geth --dev
```

**Console2:**

```
geth --dev attach
> miner.start()
true
>
```

In console 1 I get messages like:

```
I0930 11:14:56.732449 miner/worker.go:339] ??  Mined block (#10 / 4486bfb7). Wait 5 blocks for confirmation
```

Should the `??` be an address? What command can I use to define the mining account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shut down `geth` using Control-C for instance #1 and Control-D for instance #2.

Then type `geth account new` to create a new account. Enter in a passphrase that you will need to remember if you want to unlock the account.

Then restart `geth` and you should see your first account (or coinbase) listed.

Comment: For future readers; I also ran [`miner.setEtherbase("myaccount")`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/JavaScript-Console#minersetetherbase) - unsure if I needed to and can't tell now...

Comment: Should not need to. Your etherbase is the first account listed in `eth.accounts`, i.e. `eth.accounts[0]`. If you want to set another account, you can use the `miner.setEtherbase(...)` command. You can also use the command line parameter `--etherbase {account}`.